# Proving relations between square cosines

Tags: trigonometry, data-analysis

I am studying data analysis and especially PCA (principal component analysis) and reviewing the very course i took a few years ago, i found a result that seems interesting but there is no proof and i can't find it myself.

Here is a capture of the slide :
[image]

(yeah i'm french), so, as far as i understood it, $\theta$ is the angle between the vector defined by the data point $e_i$ and the projection plane. I guess it is useful to measure the quality of the representation of the data, the thing is i couldn't prove this result myself.

What am i missing ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

These are direction cosines.Note that $ O f e_1 $ is a right angle.$\theta$ is angle of elevation.

$$ \frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{L^2}  =1 $$

$$ \cos^2 \theta_1 +\cos^2 \theta_2 +\cos^2 \theta_3 = l^2+m^2+n^2 =1 $$

$$ \cos^2 \theta = \frac{x^2 + y^2 }{L^2}. $$

Comment: i guess $\theta_3$ for you is $\theta$ is the image i posted. But what are those letters for ?

Comment: or is $\theta_3$ the angle between the vector and some third axis assuming we limit ourselves to a 3-dimension space ?

Comment: Yes. $ \theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ are  angles between coordinate axes $x,y,z$ and the 3D diagonal. They are $not$ in x-y plane.

Comment: ok, but just to be sure, $\theta$ is the angle between the point $e_i$ in the space $R^3$ and its projection $f_i$ in the the 2D plane defined by x and y, or "axis 1" and "axis 2" in the illustration i posted

Comment: What is L ? Is it the length of $O e_i$ ?

Comment: And how did you go from the second line to the third one ? More generally how do you find "from scratch" that 3rd line (like only from pythagore and basic trigonometrics results)

Comment: Yes. $\theta$ is the angle in the vertical plane between L and its x-y $projection$. Actually the Pythagorean theorem is a special case of this situation. It is a 3D $ generalization$